# how to modify the strokeColor of button in android

Tags: android

I want to implement a OutlineButton for my app, when i modify the strockcolor of the button, it doesn't work.StrickColor is seems to transparent forerver.

this is my drawable file outline_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/primary" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
</shape>
```

layout

```
    <Button
        style="@style/OutlineButton"
        android:id="@+id/btn_nfc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
        android:text="@string/read_nfc" />
```

themes:

```
<style name="OutlineButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/outline_button</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

and i change the themes to:

```
<style name="OutlineButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/outline_button</item>
    <item name="android:strokeColor">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:strokeWidth">2.0</item>
    <item name="android:color">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

still doesn't work. so how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this problem:--

**By using Material Button**

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/outlined_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="Outlined Button"
        app:cornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/periwinkle_blue"
        app:strokeWidth="2dp" />
```

**By Using Button but style parent as TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button**

```
<Button
        style="@style/OutlineButton"
        android:id="@+id/btn_nfc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="read_nfc" />

style:-
 
   <style name="OutlineButton" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/test</item>
    <item name="android:strokeColor">@color/green_50</item>
    <item name="android:strokeWidth">2</item>
</style>
```

*or you can give parent as "parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"*

Comment: Thanks for you reply, the first resolution by changing style to "@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton" can show the outline border, but background is gray, it should be white. second resolution doesn't work.